# Unable to click Admin Console button during OpenFire installation on Mac

Tags: openfire

I have been trying to install openfire server(4.0.1 version) on mac OSX El Capitan (version 10.11.3) for development and testing purpose.

I also installed latest jre

I tried to run open fire from preference but always give error attached in screenshot

What is the solution to this error?

Thank you in advance.
[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiP0t.png)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No. I decided not to go this way.

Comment: then what is another way?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after install OpenFire 4.0.3

1- Make sure you have JAVA 7 or higher

```
java -version
```

2- Make sure OpenFire can see your JAVA and has permissions to execute by going to console and type:

```
sudo su
  <admin_pass>
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
chmod -R 777 /usr/local/openfire/bin
cd /usr/local/openfire/bin
./openfire.sh
```

TIP: restart your machine

TIP2: the lauching logs are at: /usr/local/openfire/launchd.stderr & launchd.stdout

TIP3: check your config, like said here: https://community.igniterealtime.org/message/179404#179404